# Ruby error related to mysql2

Tags: aptana, bundle, mysql2

I am running Aptana Studio 3 on windows 7 ultimate. I opened an existing project (site+ application) and I have to make several modifications. When "`Run server`", 
I get this error:

> `c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in resolve`: Could not find gem '`mysql2 (= 0.2.6) x86-mingw32`' in the gems available on this machine. (`Bundler::GemNotFound`)

Thing is I installed the mysql2 gem, from terminal, but i still get this error. What am I doing wrong?